# NFS mount edits on local NFS-exported filesystem change permissions on the remote NFS mount

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

I believe there is a `noperm` or something to that effect option in NFS, but how do I make sure that if server A is exporting `/opt/nfs` and it is mounted as an NFS mount on server b `/export/serverA` that local changes to files on server A `/opt/nfs` folder do not change ownership or permissions on the server B `/export/serverA` filesystem?

Assume RHEL 6 for OS.